# how can I move the element at auto complete jQuery-UI into input type text when clicked

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I tried to move text at auto complete using jQuery-UI into input type text. I just can click the auto complete text and move it into input.

insert.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title> Home Page </title>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryui.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo"
 <form id='form1' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='simpanpage.php' method='post'>

  Label : <input type=text name=label id=label> <input type=submit value=save>

 </form> 
";
?>

<script>
$( "#label" ).autocomplete({
 source: "searchlabel.php",
 minlength: 1,
 select: function( event, ui ) {
   log( ui.item ?
   "Selected Label: " + ui.item.value :
   "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
 }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

searchlabel.php

```
<?php 

include 'koneks.php';     

$dba = new database;

$dba->connectMYSQL(); 

$arr = array();

if(isset($_GET['term']))
{
    $term = $_GET['term'];

    $query2 = "SELECT label FROM pages WHERE label LIKE '%$term%'";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2) 
    or die();

    while($ans = mysql_fetch_row($result2)){

    $arr[] = $ans[0];
    }

    echo json_encode($arr);
}
?>
```

Can you please solve my problem? Maybe something is wrong with my code here.

Comment: Is data populated in autocomplete?

Comment: @Runcorn yes but i can't click them.

Comment: So you want to copy the selected value to another input box when the suggestion is clicked..??

Comment: @Outlooker : yup i want it move into input after clicked the selected value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this could help u mate..:) Inside the select property of uiautocomplete assign the value to the new input box field

```
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#temp").val(ui.item.value);
        }
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9rz6mz57/)